# JFreeChart can't remove lines of graphic in range of drawing

Tags: java, graphics, jfreechart

I have a problem, when program draw graphic with "limit's"

**my graphic now**

[image: Graphic with limit's]

But I need something like this

[image]

piece of code, where I draw graphic:

```
private XYSeries series;
double R0 = -40;
double A = 20;
series = new XYSeries("r(fi) = " + R0 +" + (" + A + "*cos(fi*3))",false);

addCoordinates(0.01,20,20);

XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("my graphic 14",
        "x", "y", xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
        true, true, true);

private void addCoordinates(double step, double rangeX, double rangeY){
    series.clear();
    for (double fi=0; fi < 2*Math.PI; fi+=step) {
        double ro = R0 + A * Math.cos(fi * 3);
        double x = ro * Math.cos(fi);
        double y = ro * Math.sin(fi);
        if(Math.abs(x) <= rangeX && Math.abs(y) <=rangeY) series.add(x,y);

    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be posting from more than one [account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6778307/bellkross); you can ask to [merge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339774/230513) them.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.